# Django form field label translations

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-forms

I have a baseform with over 20 fields. Then I have about 15 other forms inheriting from that form, passing in a parameter called fields which the baseform uses to delete all other fields. Best explain via example:

```
class BaseForm(forms.Form):
    reportid = forms.HiddenInput()
    fromdate = forms.DateField(label=_("From"), widget=widgets.AdminDateWidget())
    todate = forms.DateField(label=_("To"), widget=widgets.AdminDateWidget())
    sort_by = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("Sort by"), choices=[])
    .......

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields')
        #Pseudo:
        ***del self.fields[field] for field not in fields***

class SubForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = ['reportid', 'todate']
        super(SubForm, self).__init__(fields=fields, *args, **kwargs)
```

The resulting form would then look like this:

```
class SubForm(forms.Form):
    reportid = forms.HiddenInput()
    todate = forms.DateField(label=_("To"), widget=widgets.AdminDateWidget())
```

My problem is that when the BaseForm is initialized for the first time, the labels are bound to the fields with the active language, and when another user logs in with another language setting (or the current user changes languages) the field labels don't update.

I've come to a solution using a dict like this:

```
labels = {
    'todate': lambda: _("To"),
    'fromdate': lambda: _("From"),
    .....
}
```

and then when initializing the baseform looping through all fields and setting

```
self.fields[field].widget.label = labels[field]()
```

Do I have any nicer (read: more pythonic) way of achieving this?

Comment: Do you use ugettext_lazy for translating fields?

Comment: @Krzysztof: Of course! That was pretty stupid, I was importing ugettext instead of ugettext_lazy... If you'll post your comment as an answer I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Django provides _lazy variants of the translation functions (for example `ugettext_lazy`) so you can ark strings for translations at the access time (as opposed to when the translation function is called).

It's documented in details at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translation